# use an existing model but require more lables

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pre-trained-model

I have a pre-trained image model that have 4 labels, In the new model I'd like to have two of the four labels and need to add one more new label. I have about 100 dataset that can be used to train the model for the new label, and would use the existing knowledge from the pretrained model for these two existing labels.
is there a way that I can train this new model with the 100 dataset based on the pre-trained model? Thanks

Comment: you have to add the data to the previously existing data and retrain either the whole thing or the final fully connected layer only.

Comment: so I need to add new training data with the existing data, and add the new label with existing labels, and then use these just train the last fully connected layer?

Comment: Have you tried by increasing the nodes in last layer to the number of classes in the dataset.

Comment: no. can you elaborate your idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can just train your last layer of fully connected for training your new label

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? Do I need to add the new lable to the existing data - this will be time consuming due to the huge amount of the existing dataset.

Comment: What is similarity of your new label with old label

Comment: What is data features of your new label?

Comment: the new label is completely different category comparing with existing labels, and I can find about 100 new dataset to train the model particular for the new label. so with this one new label and hundred new dataset, how should I set up the training process by leveraging the existing model?

Comment: you can use data augmentation to make more new data then rearrenge your lable set then train your last layer

Comment: how to train just the last layer?

Comment: if you use torch you can check this out.https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html

Comment: model.classifier[i] = nn.Linear(4096,num_classes)

Comment: then torch.optim.Adam(model.classifier.parameters(), lr=LR)